# Duplicate emails being produced only through Outlook via Laravel App

Tags: outlook, smtp, office365

We are using a web application to send out mail. Email is sent and received as expected on a server level and in GMail. However, when messages are pushed to our client's Office365 (Outlook), instead of getting one copy they are getting duplicates.

This is how the app works. You can send emails to a number of people (1,5,20, etc). It's all the same message, subject, etc. It's the same email.

The app sends you a copy. Just one. That's how it is supposed to work. Within their Office365 (Outlook) email account, they get their one copy, and then another copy for each recipient (that's not supposed to happen). So, if you email 5 people, instead of getting one email back, they get 6.

The thing is, this program has run flawlessly for nearly a year. Out of the blue, this glitch started happening.

We have had no code changes, no vendor updates, or anything of the sort on the web application side of things that would trigger since before the time this glitch started happening. When we tested locally, and on the live server, with GMail credentials, the app continues to work as it should.

We are sending out mail via SMTP.

The security protocol is "tls".

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail that describes the core Laravel mail function we are using to send out mail.

The client contacted Microsoft support -- who basically said "I don't know. Not my problem".

I don't know where else to turn, or what other steps to take to debug.

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you configure a dummy POP3/SMTP account in Outlook against your Office 365 mailbox (make sure you specify invalid POP3 server to avoid downloading your whole mailbox) and send a message to multiple recipients?

Comment: We have not tried that method yet. We will try that test out next. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: We tried that with no luck. They got the standard 1 email back, not duplicates. Thanks for your insight though

Comment: Then the software vendor (Laravel) has to figure that one out.

Comment: Was experiencing similar issues. Microsoft are working on it. See this link https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_exchon-mso_o365b/sending-out-duplicate-emails-when-sending-through/d0ffc4be-14a9-492e-9336-3ce53098e9d6